# Convergence of Iteration with Sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Consider a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, and the iteration

$$ x_{k+1} = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^{k} f( x_i ) $$

for some given initial condition $x_1 \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Under what conditions on $f$ is the sequence $\{x_k\}_k$ converging to some $\bar{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$?